# AS3 - Url to leave movie and go to new link?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

When I add a link to text it takes me to a new tab.  How do I make it so that it leaves the movie and goes to that link?

Comment: are you pushing htmlText into your textfield? if so, do you have "_blank" in that HTML string? If so, change it to _self or just take it out and it should default to keeping it inside of your current browser window.

Comment: It is TLF text. I added a URL in the properties box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ADVANCED CHARACTER tab, you have entered a "Link" value, correct?  If so, just change the "Target" value directly beneath the "Link" and set it to "_self".

[image: Like this]